# Update from two differents table with postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I want to update a table with postgresql.

In fact, I have a table (`TABLE_ONE`) with two column (`old_id` and `new_id`). I have a second table (`TABLE_TWO`) with `colums (id,column1,column2,...)`.

I want to update the column id from `TABLE_TWO`. The wanted behavior is that when `TABLE_ONE.id = TABLE_TWO.old_id`, we set id to `new_id`.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want an [`UPDATE FROM`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-update.html) statement:

```
UPDATE table_one
SET table_one.id = table_two.id
FROM table_two
WHERE table_one.id = table_two.old_id;
```